# Visual C++ memory block padding

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I am currently working on getting a large project stable before doing testing, and appear to have random crashes in release mode.

Is there a way to increase memory block padding to recognize out of bounds access violations more easily? As well, can you recommend any other debugging techniques that check as much as possible? (Performance is no issue).

To clarify: I am looking for a way to increase the memory block pad bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft provides the [Page Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) provided in Application Verifier.  This mode of executing your program will help you immediately find buffer overruns.

Comment: Expanding on this, I suggest Application Verifier with DebugDiag set to log all debug messages. When some heap corruption occurs, DebugDiag will catch the resulting exception and create a crash dump, as well as logging the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Load crash dump to visual studio and run debugger after crash, check call stack etc..

Answer (score 0):

If the crashes are only in Release mode, I suggest you look for uninitialized variables first.